# Is it possible to bind the local socket to a static port in a QuickFIX/n Initiator?

Tags: c#, quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixn

QuickFIX/n listens to a "random" port when it establishes a connection. A quick Google search shows that QuickFIX/j has the config settings *SocketLocalPort* and *SocketLocalHost* that allows us to bind the local socket to a host/port.

Is this also possible in QuickFIX/n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, I cannot see that the .NET implementation supports this configuration parameter. So the local port will always be ephemeral.

- [.Net
  Initiator Source](https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/blob/master/QuickFIXn/Transport/SocketInitiator.cs)
- [Socket
  Settings](https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/blob/master/QuickFIXn/SocketSettings.cs)